# Como coletar o tempo de execução de atividades realizada no banco de dados sem estar executando direto no mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso obter o tempo de execução de diversos inserts , updates , alter tables entre outra atividade que eu exerço no banco , eu sei que se eu fizesse direto no mysql ele me retornaria ao final da operação porém estou executando um script em js para realizar diversas operações , esse tempo de execução fica salvo em algum se sim onde eu posso pegar , se não qual soluções vocês me dão .

Banco que uso MYSQL
exemplo :
O scrip execulta 1000 inserts , depois 500 updates , 200 delete ... , gostaria de pegar o tempo de execução disso para no final fazer um comparativo que almejo .

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução rápida é criar duas variáveis, Horainicial e Horafinal, ao iniciar a consulta você atribui a variável Horainicial a hora do computador e ao terminar a consulta, atribui valor a Horafinal e verfica o tempo decorrido vendo a diferença entre uma e outra.